# JSONAPI resources: serialize a namespaced model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json-api, jsonapi-resources

I'm trying to use [JSONAPI Resources](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) in a Rails engine and I've defined `DokiCore::Tenant` (the model) in doki_core/app/models/tenant.rb and `DokiCore::TenantResource` in doki_core/app/resources/tenant_resource.rb. When I attempt to serialize to hash, I encounter the following error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `tenant_path' for #<Module:0x007f9d04208778>
>   from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@doki/gems/jsonapi-resources-0.6.1/lib/jsonapi/link_builder.rb:77:in`public_send'

The resource uses `model_name` to let it know where the model actually is:

```
module DokiCore
  class TenantResource < JSONAPI::Resource
    model_name 'DokiCore::Tenant'
    # ...
  end
end
```

I'm trying to output the hash for a tenant like so:

```
tenant = DokiCore::Tenant.find(1); 
resource = DokiCore::TenantResource.new(tenant, nil); 
serializer = JSONAPI::ResourceSerializer.new(DokiCore::TenantResource); 
serializer.serialize_to_hash(resource);
```

which is where the error happens.

How can I get the links to work correctly and/or disable them? I assume this is there it adds the URL to the resource as a link under the "links" key in the outputted json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorted this out. If your routes are namespaced in any way, your resources also need to be namespaced to match. My routes look something like:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :tenants
  end
end
```

So the resource needs to be namespaced the same way:

```
tenant = DokiCore::Tenant.find(1); 
resource = DokiCore::API::V1::TenantResource.new(tenant, nil); 
serializer = JSONAPI::ResourceSerializer.new(DokiCore::API::V1::TenantResource); 
serializer.serialize_to_hash(resource);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way to serialize your namespaced data is by using the [jsonapi-utils](https://github.com/b2beauty/jsonapi-utils) gem. You will just need to do something like this:

```
class API::V1::UsersController < API::V1::BaseController
  def index
    jsonapi_render json: User.all
  end
end
```

The gem is based on JSON API Resources, bringing a Rails way to get data serialized with JSON API's specs.

Comment: I get no such method jsonapi_render - any ideas?